# Why this code work only once [Android-canvas]

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I want to draw circle in canvas. I use function to do id:

```
      public static  void add()
        {
            float a = 20 + (new Random()).nextInt(width-40);
            float b = 20 + (new Random()).nextInt(height-40);


            paint.setColor(Color.rgb(13, 13, 13));
            c.drawCircle(a, b, r, paint);

            paint.setColor(Color.rgb(119, 119, 119));
            c.drawCircle(a, b, r-3, paint);
        }
```

It works only once, when it called from "onDraw".

p.s.
paint, width, height, c - public varibles.

UPD.:

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canv)
    {
        super.onDraw(canv);
        c = canv;
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        c.drawPaint(paint);
        add();
    }
```

Comment: move you draw in `onDraw` and call `invalidate()` to refresh/update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onDraw()` will be called whenever the view needs to re-draw itself. This can be due to many reasons, like layout changing, scrolling etc.

You can also call `invalidate()` on a View to cause a re-draw.

If you are going to draw at a very high rate, like touch painting or some game etc, consider using a `TextureView` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I did it as follows.

1) Define a custom View.

2) on its onDraw method, do this creating/showing circle.

3) call invalidate() method in the last line of onDraw method of custom View.

let me know if it works

Comment: 1) I have View Class. All functions in this class
  
2) I add onDraw method to the post
  
3) I need to draw circles not once, but on touch(function "add" calls on touch)
How I can do it? I don`t understand third tip.